# How to undo factory reset in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

I had reset my laptop to factory settings without deleting personal files, but one of my software was deleted with its own database.
Any suggestions for how to undo this reset effect? There is no system restore  point.

What can I do to recover that software or at least the database mdf and ldf file

Comment: Data recovery will be the only thing you can do at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: I suggest starting with the solution for recovering in the case of hard drive corruption or bad sectors. It's not what you have, but it'll probably be the closest for resolution purposes.

Comment: Assuming the database isn't some intractable proprietary format....

Comment: Restore your data from a backup.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have none.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the integrated Windows 10 reset, I believe it stores the files to be able to roll back. You may also check if `C:\Windows.old\Program Files` has any relevant files.

Comment: the aplication is in Windows.old but data base files are not. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know where the database files are regularly stored?

Comment: yes i do, right in the software main branch

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use data recovery software, for instance [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

This tool is powerful free data recovery software designed to recover lost partitions.

Among other features it can, TestDisk can:

- Fix partition table, recover deleted partition

  - Undelete files from FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2 filesystem
  - Copy files from deleted FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions.

Which accomplish what you want  to achieve in terms of getting you data back

Hope this helps